# How to include a C# .dll wrapper in a C# project?

Tags: c#

So I have a C# project and I'm trying to add USB functionality to it via the Silicon Labs CP2112 USB to i2c bridge. They provide drivers as 2 .dll files: SLABHIDtoSMBus.dll and SLABHIDDevice.dll (which apparently is needed at runtime). I've also found a SLABCP2112.cs file that is supposed to allow the dll to be used in C#.

I've added the SLABCP2112.cs to my project successfully and Intellisense recognizes the functions. The problem is that when I run the program it always throws an exception that the SLABHIDtoSMBUS.dll is not found(System.DllNotFoundException). I've tried moving the dll to various locations such as the main project folder, the 'USB' folder in the project where I've included the SLABCP2112.cs, the Windows SysWOW64 folder and finally in the c#'s projects 'bin' folder.

Placing it in the bin folder still throws an exception but changes the error to a bad image error or something similar. For good measure I've tried to add the .dll's as References in the project but this causes an error "invalid or unsupported type".

I'm assuming the problem is still that the compiler doesn't know where to look for the dll files, so where should I put them? Or if not, how do I get this working?

Comment: the error that you got when you finally put it in the correct location usually indicates that you're trying to load a 32-bit only dll in a 64-bit app

Comment: @Aluan: Thank you! For clarification, correct location being the bin folder?

Comment: in the menu, go to Project then project Properties, Build, and then Platform Target

Comment: @Aluan: You win! I thought for sure I had grabbed the 64 bit driver but I guess not. Putting the 64 bit driver in the bin folder worked. Problem now is it isn't wanting to connect but I'd bet that's a different issue.

Comment: Glad I could help. The connection issue is definitely unrelated.